# Set UICulture for whole application instead of individual pages in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have below code in my page,

```
    Dim ci As New CultureInfo("en-US")
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci
    MyBase.InitializeCulture()
```

On page this works fine. When I change culture from dropdown, it sets different culture. Problem is, this works for single page. As soon as I move to next page, culture is set to default. I don't want to write above code on each page.

If anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set the culture inside the `AcquireRequestState` method in your global.asax

> Occurs when ASP.NET acquires the current state (for example, session state) that is associated with the current request.

```
Sub Application_AcquireRequestState(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If Not HttpContext.Current Is Nothing AndAlso Not HttpContext.Current.Session Is Nothing Then
        If (Session("culture") IsNot Nothing) Then
            Dim ci As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo(Session("culture").ToString())
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

#### More Information

[MSDN: AcquireRequestState Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.acquirerequeststate(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Comment: Well, I store culture name in session when change language. I cannot use that session in application begin request method. I already tried this.

Comment: I updated your answer, I tried this, but didn't work. Session always returns nothing.

Comment: `Session_Start` called only once when I start application. When I change culture, it didn't call session start method again.

Comment: Its not working. I tried but it didn't call that method when I navigate to next page. I added this event in global.asax, is it correct?